# I Can't work with NERDCommenter

Tags: vim

I installed NerdCommenter like how it should be installed. And I read the help files. So, for commenting a line I need to do `<leader>c$`.

I also read that the leader key is `\` by default. But it didn't work for me. I never used the leader key so I think I am doing something wrong.

Can anybody help me for using the basic commenting and uncommenting selected lines using nerdcommenter?

Comment: The shortcut for commenting the rest of a line is `<leader>c$`, with the default leader that would be `\c$`. Please, show us the content of your .vimrc and also do `:verbose map <leader>`.

Comment: I didn't set anything for NERDCommenter in my .vimrc. Because there are already default key bindings from NERDCommenter

Comment: Maybe other things are conflicting so you should show it.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qs9lp55mi0r56az/.vimrc Here you can find my vimrc file. When doing the command: '\' does not do anything, then when I do 'c', then row is deleted and i switch to insert mode...

Comment: After I did `:verbose map <leader>`. NERDCommenter does react. But I get errors... I get following error https://www.dropbox.com/s/hynhx37rhztsgh3/error.txt . I get this error but if I continue then it inserts /*...*/ comments correctly. What I need as comment characters is following: -- ...

Comment: It looks like a nerdcommenter bug, then. You should report it to the author.

Comment: Your vimrc is full of redundant and mutually nullifying commands, you should clean it up a bit.

Comment: I know indeed. thanks for the warning

Comment: I preffer [Commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) by Tim Pope which work much nicer IMHO (and doesn't utilise leader key but use `gc` instead).

Answer (score 10):

## Problem

On many non-English keyboards, the backslash `\` is only accessible through a <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key combination. This makes the default setting of the `<Leader>` character rather impractical for these users. Moreover, `<Leader>` key combinations are subject to a default 1000ms time-out. This can be observed by the disappearance of the `<Leader>` key at the right edge of the command line.
So, non-English keyboard users need to be real quick typists for <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> to work. Failure to do so, results in an undesired `cc` line change.

Here is an example of a German keyboard layout with the backslash-bearing key on the top row, third from right:
[image: German keyboard layout]

## Solution

Non-English keyboard users are advised to change the `<Leader>` key from the `\` character to the more accessible <kbd>,</kbd> key. Vim beginners should also consider a slightly longer 1500ms time-out. Here is what needs to be added to `~/.vimrc`

```
let mapleader=","
set timeout timeoutlen=1500
```

One final caveat; these **changes only take effect after completely exiting Vim.** Resourcing with `:source $MYVIMRC` will not work!

Now, one can use <kbd>,</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> for commenting with NERD Commenter.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I was noticing that it wouldn't flat out deny the command, but would say "No Error" and just not do anything. I read the install instructions for NERDCommenter very carefully and noticed this bit:

> After the 'Classic' or 'Pathogen' install, make sure that you have
>   filetype plugins enabled, as the script makes use of |'commentstring'|
>   where possible (which is usually set in a filetype plugin). See
>   |filetype-plugin-on| for details, but basically, stick this in your
>   vimrc:
>
> filetype plugin on

Even though I'd used NeoBundle rather than Pathogen, I tried that, and after a restart, voila. Hope it helps.